# What's the difference between Topic and Parameter?

Tags: ros, topic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Topic gets data from Publisher.
What's the difference between Topic and Parameter?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/65853/what%27s-the-difference-between-topic-and-parameter?/) by [Ichiro suzuki](https://answers.ros.org/users/5224/ichiro-suzuki/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-06-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Parameters are stored centrally on the parameter server and continue to live once whatever set that dies. They usually only contain simple data and can be set during launch. Parameters are usually used as configuration parameters while topics provide streaming changing data.

Technically topics form a direct connection between nodes, while parameters are stored and read from the parameter server.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-06-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A topic is intended for a stream of changing data while a parameter is something you set at the begin and don't change that often.

But you probably mean the difference between a publisher and a topic? A topic is a channel on which a publisher publishes data. It is a kind of whiteboard (the topic) on which a person (a publisher) writes things, but multiple people (publishers) can write on the whiteboard. It is also possible that no one is writing on the whiteboard (no publishers) but there are people (subscribers) watching it.

---

Originally posted by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) with karma: 2573 on 2013-06-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2